# Access master page control on web user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

i have a aspx page which is inherited from the master page and i am dynamically adding the Webuser control inside the placeholder in aspx page .

i want to acces the label which is inside the master page in my web user control .

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240564/how-do-you-access-user-controls-on-a-masterpage-from-the-aspcontent-page-using

Comment: @PaulMcCowat i want to access the master page label on the web user control how can i get this master page label on my web user control

Comment: If any of the suggestions don't work for you, you will need to post some code of your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty nice [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103719/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062409-1.aspx#postadlink) on this subject by 4guysfromrolla with tons of useful links like this [one](http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("YourLabelNameHere")).Text = "Hello";
```